# Getting the Avg Age with multiple Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a query that is taking all of our Divisions of our Company and is giving me the Avg Age for that Division, displaying the headcount, and the number of employee turnover for a specific year.

What I am trying to do is to get the Avg_Age for all of the Parameters that are selected.

My desired output would be to add up the total headcount and then get the Avg of any Divisions that are selected. So Avg of 51 + 40 / 2

[Current Output when Ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL3Cy.png)

[Desired Output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61alj.png)

```
        SELECT SUM(E.EOM_RECORDSTATUS_EFF) AS HEADCOUNT, SUM(E.TERMSTATUS_EFF) AS TURNOVER,
            CASE WHEN SUM(E.EOM_RECORDSTATUS_EFF) > 0 THEN (SUM(CASE WHEN E.EOM_RECORDSTATUS_EFF = 1 THEN A.AGES ELSE 0 END) / SUM(E.EOM_RECORDSTATUS_EFF)) ELSE 0 END AS AVG_AGE
        FROM RPT_EMPLOYEECENSUS_ASOF AS E
            INNER JOIN HR_AGES AS A ON A.HRYEAR = E.HRYEAR AND A.HRPERIOD = E.HRPERIOD AND A.AGES_DATE = E.BIRTHDATE
            INNER JOIN HR_TENURE AS T ON T.HRYEAR = E.HRYEAR AND T.HRPERIOD = E.HRPERIOD AND T.TENURE_DATE = E.SENIOR_DATE
            INNER JOIN dbo.HR_EMPUSERFIELD_DESCS D on E.EMPLOYEE = D.EMPLOYEE
            inner join dbo.HR_POSUSERFIELDS pu on pu.POSITION = E.POSITION
        WHERE 
            pu.[DIVISION/SECTION] in ('ACUTE/ADMI','ACUTE/EM','ACUTE/FB') AND
            E.FISCALYEAR = 2020 AND 
            E.FISCALPERIOD = 1 AND 
            concat(rtrim(E.PROCESS_LEVEL), rtrim(E.DEPARTMENT)) in ('CALL10100','CALL10654','CALL11100','CALL11654','CALL12400','CALL12401','CALL12402',
            'CALL12403','CALL12405','CALL12406','CALL12407','CALL12500','CALL13100','CALL13654','CALL14100','CALL14654','CALL15100','CALL15654','CALL15700',
            'CALL15750','CALL15754','CALL15771','CALL16100','CALL17100','CALL17654','CALL18100','CALL18654','CALL19100','CALL19654','CALL20100','CALL20654',
            'CALL21100','CALL21654','CALL22100','CALL22654','CALL23100','CALL23654','CALL24100','CALL24654','CALL25100','CALL25654','CALL26100','CALL26350',
            'CALL26371','CALL26654','CALL27100','CALL27350','CALL27371','CALL27654','CALL28100','CALL28350','CALL28371','CALL28654','CALL29100','CALL29350','CALL29371',
            'CALL29654','CALL30100','CALL30350','CALL30371','CALL30654','CALL31100','CALL31350','CALL31371','CALL31654','CALL32100','CALL32654','CALL33100','CALL33200',
            'CALL33654','CALL34100','CALL35100','CALL36100','CALL36654','CALL37100','CALL37350','CALL37371','CALL37654','CALL38100','CALL38371','CALL38654','CALL39608',
            'CALL39654','CALL40100','CALL40654','CALL41100','CALL41350','CALL41371','CALL41654','CALL42100','CALL42654','CALL43100','CALL43350','CALL43371','CALL43654',
            'CALL44100','CALL44654','CALL45100','CALL45350','CALL46100','CALL46350','CALL46371','CALL46654','CALL47100','CALL47350','CALL47371','CALL47654','CALL48100',
            'CALL48654','CALL50100','CALL50350','CALL50371','CALL50654','CALL51100','CALL51350','CALL51371','CALL51654','CALL52100','CALL52350','CALL52371','CALL52654',
            'CALL53100','CALL53350','CALL53371','CALL53654','CALL54100','CALL54350','CALL54371','CALL54654','CALL55100','CALL55350','CALL55371','CALL55654','CALL56100',
            'CALL56371','CALL56654','CALL57100','CALL57654','CALL58100','CALL58350','CALL58371','CALL58654','CALL59100','CALL59120','CALL59350','CALL59371','CALL59654','
            CALL60100','CALL60350','CALL60371','CALL60654','CALL61100','CALL61350','CALL61371','CALL61654','CALL62100','CALL62350','CALL62371','CALL62654','CALL63100',
            'CALL63350','CALL63654','CALL64100','CALL64371','CALL64654','CALL65100','CALL65350','CALL65371','CALL65654','CALL66100','CALL66654','CALL66700','CALL66754',
            'CALL67100','CALL67350','CALL67371','CALL67654','CALL68100','CALL68654','CALL69100','CALL69350','CALL69371','CALL69608','CALL69654','CALL70000','CALL70100',
            'CALL70200','CALL70225','CALL70590','CALL70595','CALL70598','CALL70605','CALL70608','CALL70610','CALL70615','CALL70620','CALL70625','CALL70640','CALL70654') AND 
            E.MASTER_EMP_STATUS not in ('1A', 'ZZ') AND 
            E.EMPLOYEE not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

        GROUP by pu.[DIVISION/SECTION]
```

Ultimately I want to use parameters like so:

```
        SELECT SUM(E.EOM_RECORDSTATUS_EFF) AS HEADCOUNT, SUM(E.TERMSTATUS_EFF) AS TURNOVER,
            CASE WHEN SUM(E.EOM_RECORDSTATUS_EFF) > 0 THEN (SUM(CASE WHEN E.EOM_RECORDSTATUS_EFF = 1 THEN A.AGES ELSE 0 END) / SUM(E.EOM_RECORDSTATUS_EFF)) ELSE 0 END AS AVG_AGE
        FROM RPT_EMPLOYEECENSUS_ASOF AS E
            INNER JOIN HR_AGES AS A ON A.HRYEAR = E.HRYEAR AND A.HRPERIOD = E.HRPERIOD AND A.AGES_DATE = E.BIRTHDATE
            INNER JOIN HR_TENURE AS T ON T.HRYEAR = E.HRYEAR AND T.HRPERIOD = E.HRPERIOD AND T.TENURE_DATE = E.SENIOR_DATE
            INNER JOIN dbo.HR_EMPUSERFIELD_DESCS D on E.EMPLOYEE = D.EMPLOYEE
            inner join dbo.HR_POSUSERFIELDS pu on pu.POSITION = E.POSITION
        WHERE 
            pu.[DIVISION/SECTION] in (@DIVISION) AND
            E.FISCALYEAR = @YEAR AND 
            E.FISCALPERIOD = @PERIOD AND 
            concat(rtrim(E.PROCESS_LEVEL), rtrim(E.DEPARTMENT)) in (@PL_DEPT) AND 
            E.MASTER_EMP_STATUS not in ('1A', 'ZZ') AND 
            E.EMPLOYEE not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

        GROUP by pu.[DIVISION/SECTION]
```

Comment: Where are you having trouble?

Comment: @HereGoes how can I get it so when I run it, it will give me my desired output. Such as getting me the Average of all of the Divisions together. Not just an average of each single division selected.

Comment: Did you try not using the GROUP BY?

Comment: @HereGoes that does work until I want to put a parameter for division. Such as at symbolDIVISION

Comment: @HereGoes If I take out the Group by pu.[DIVISION/SECTION] it gives me an error that I need it in a GROUP by Clause

Answer (score 0):

Try using a subquery... without your data I can't really test it.

```
SELECT  SUM(HEADCOUNT) AS HEADCOUNT, SUM(TURNOVER) AS TURNOVER ,
    CASE WHEN SUM(EOM_RECORDSTATUS_EFF) <> 0 THEN
            SUM(AGES) / SUM(EOM_RECORDSTATUS_EFF)
    ELSE 0
    END  AVG_AGE
  FROM (
SELECT SUM(E.EOM_RECORDSTATUS_EFF) AS HEADCOUNT, SUM(E.TERMSTATUS_EFF) AS TURNOVER, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN E.EOM_RECORDSTATUS_EFF = 1 THEN A.AGES ELSE 0 END)  AGES ,SUM(E.EOM_RECORDSTATUS_EFF) EOM_RECORDSTATUS_EFF

        FROM RPT_EMPLOYEECENSUS_ASOF AS E
            INNER JOIN HR_AGES AS A ON A.HRYEAR = E.HRYEAR AND A.HRPERIOD = E.HRPERIOD AND A.AGES_DATE = E.BIRTHDATE
            INNER JOIN HR_TENURE AS T ON T.HRYEAR = E.HRYEAR AND T.HRPERIOD = E.HRPERIOD AND T.TENURE_DATE = E.SENIOR_DATE
          INNER JOIN dbo.HR_EMPUSERFIELD_DESCS D on E.EMPLOYEE = D.EMPLOYEE
          inner join HR_POSUSERFIELDS pu on pu.POSITION = E.POSITION
        WHERE 
            pu.[DIVISION/SECTION] in ('ACUTE/ADMI','ACUTE/EM','ACUTE/FB') AND
            E.FISCALYEAR = 2020 AND 
            E.FISCALPERIOD = 1 AND 
            concat(rtrim(E.PROCESS_LEVEL), rtrim(E.DEPARTMENT)) in ('CALL10100','CALL10654','CALL11100','CALL11654','CALL12400','CALL12401','CALL12402',
            'CALL12403','CALL12405','CALL12406','CALL12407','CALL12500','CALL13100','CALL13654','CALL14100','CALL14654','CALL15100','CALL15654','CALL15700',
            'CALL15750','CALL15754','CALL15771','CALL16100','CALL17100','CALL17654','CALL18100','CALL18654','CALL19100','CALL19654','CALL20100','CALL20654',
            'CALL21100','CALL21654','CALL22100','CALL22654','CALL23100','CALL23654','CALL24100','CALL24654','CALL25100','CALL25654','CALL26100','CALL26350',
            'CALL26371','CALL26654','CALL27100','CALL27350','CALL27371','CALL27654','CALL28100','CALL28350','CALL28371','CALL28654','CALL29100','CALL29350','CALL29371',
            'CALL29654','CALL30100','CALL30350','CALL30371','CALL30654','CALL31100','CALL31350','CALL31371','CALL31654','CALL32100','CALL32654','CALL33100','CALL33200',
            'CALL33654','CALL34100','CALL35100','CALL36100','CALL36654','CALL37100','CALL37350','CALL37371','CALL37654','CALL38100','CALL38371','CALL38654','CALL39608',
            'CALL39654','CALL40100','CALL40654','CALL41100','CALL41350','CALL41371','CALL41654','CALL42100','CALL42654','CALL43100','CALL43350','CALL43371','CALL43654',
            'CALL44100','CALL44654','CALL45100','CALL45350','CALL46100','CALL46350','CALL46371','CALL46654','CALL47100','CALL47350','CALL47371','CALL47654','CALL48100',
            'CALL48654','CALL50100','CALL50350','CALL50371','CALL50654','CALL51100','CALL51350','CALL51371','CALL51654','CALL52100','CALL52350','CALL52371','CALL52654',
            'CALL53100','CALL53350','CALL53371','CALL53654','CALL54100','CALL54350','CALL54371','CALL54654','CALL55100','CALL55350','CALL55371','CALL55654','CALL56100',
            'CALL56371','CALL56654','CALL57100','CALL57654','CALL58100','CALL58350','CALL58371','CALL58654','CALL59100','CALL59120','CALL59350','CALL59371','CALL59654','
            CALL60100','CALL60350','CALL60371','CALL60654','CALL61100','CALL61350','CALL61371','CALL61654','CALL62100','CALL62350','CALL62371','CALL62654','CALL63100',
            'CALL63350','CALL63654','CALL64100','CALL64371','CALL64654','CALL65100','CALL65350','CALL65371','CALL65654','CALL66100','CALL66654','CALL66700','CALL66754',
            'CALL67100','CALL67350','CALL67371','CALL67654','CALL68100','CALL68654','CALL69100','CALL69350','CALL69371','CALL69608','CALL69654','CALL70000','CALL70100',
            'CALL70200','CALL70225','CALL70590','CALL70595','CALL70598','CALL70605','CALL70608','CALL70610','CALL70615','CALL70620','CALL70625','CALL70640','CALL70654') AND 
            E.MASTER_EMP_STATUS not in ('1A', 'ZZ') AND 
            E.EMPLOYEE not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

      GROUP by pu.[DIVISION/SECTION]) x
```